# UTF-8 NO-BREAK SPACE causing problems with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios

I'm parsing some UTF8 text which contains the UTF-8 NO-BREAK SPACE (C2A0) instead of the regular space characters and this is causing issues with NSXMLParser.

So for example "I am a string" containing 3 regular space characters would be passed as a whole string to parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string.

However "I am a string" containing 3 NO-BREAK-SPACES instead of regular spaces results in 4 invocations of parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string with 4 sub-strings.

I just want to extract "I am a string", is there any neat solution for making NSURLConnection not break it into substrings if it encounters these UTF8 characters?

I do not have control over the input - its coming from a server as UTF8 encoded XML over HTTP.

Comment: Is this HTML or XML? What's surrounding that text? Tags?  Quote marks?  Do you have a DTD defined in the file?

Comment: Its XML with the text surrounded by tags.

Comment: DTD at the top?  Something like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Hi, yes, exactly as you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Find some never used Unicode character - some symbol - and using NSString change the space character to something else, then extract what you want, and do the reverse coding on the strings.

EDIT: So lets say you get the web page as a NSData object:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *nStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\uC2A0" withString:@"\u2208"];
NSData *nData = [[nStr ]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// do your parsing
// for each parsed string
NSString *nStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2208" withString: @"\uC2A0"];
```

this will get your the exact input strings at the end. But maybe you just want to forget about those Unicode spaces, just turn them into real spaces:

```
NSString *nStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2208" withString: @" "];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *nStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\uC2A0" withString:@"\u2208"];
NSData *nData = [[nStr ]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You could even look for double spaces and replace them with a single one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, change the space character where? I don't have control over the input, its coming from a server.